# Silverlight Datagrid grouping by year, month, week

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, grouping

I am using Silverlight RIA with EF and I have an entity with e.g. fields Date, Field1, Field2, ...
Binding the data on LoadOperation_Completed works fine. However, I need to group the data by Year, Month, Week. What is the proposed method? I've  tried

```
 public void  loadOp_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    LoadOperation<MyEntity> loadOp = sender as LoadOperation<MyEntity>;

    List<MyEntity> list = ((LoadOperation<MyEntity>)sender).Entities.ToList();

    PagedCollectionView collection = new PagedCollectionView(list);

    collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(**???**));
    this.MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = collection;
 }
```

but I don't know what my PropertyGroupDescription should be.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add properties called `Year`, `Month` and `Week` and base them on your date field:

```
public int Year
{
   get {  return myDate.Year; }
}
```

Then group by Year, Month, Week :)

Comment: OK I did that by creating a partial class of my entity and adding the extra properties as described. However, in the Group Header of my grid I get "Year: (450 items)"...the year value is missing...

Comment: The answer is to decorate the properties with [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]